# What prevents rm /dev/null?

Tags: linux, unix, freebsd

What is the mechanism by which `rm /dev/null` is prevented?  Specifically on FreeBSD, but I'm just as interested in all other Unix based systems.

Comment: Common logic, you can't remove nothing ;)

Comment: Have you tried ?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You can actually delete `/dev/null` as the root user on Linux and BSD systems. Of course, once the system is rebooted `/dev/null` will be restored. Without rebooting also it is possible to restore `/dev/null` using the `mknod` command.

Answer (score 12):

Permissions - unless you are running as `root` (super-user) or possibly one of a select few other users or groups (`bin` or `sys`), you do not have write permission in the `/dev/` directory, and therefore cannot remove anything from the directory.

If you are `root`, then you could remove it - but your system would be extremely unhappy.  You could recreate it, using the `mknod` command (or perhaps the `mknod()` system call).  Or you could create a plain file, but that would not have the same special properties as the 'real' `/dev/null` and would leave your system severely crippled.

It is not a good area for experimentation!  (And, if you must experiment, I recommend using a VM rather than your main machine.)